# How can I reference the beta version of typescript defenition of office JS using NPM?

Tags: typescript, office-js, office-js-helpers

As per this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js) the beta versions are in the `dist` folder under the package. but how do i refence this file in my project?

Comment: Could you share with us how your project is set up? Do you use npm to manage dependencies? Do you have access to an html file where you can add `<script>` tags? Are you using any build tools like webpack or gulp?

Comment: @evenstar I created the project using `create react app` and generated the scaffolding using `yo office` [yeoman office generator](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office). I selected the typescript option while generating. And webpack is used.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here to open a related guide on how to update the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-get-started-react#update-the-app) after you installed the office.js

Note that the guide pulled the library into `public/index.html` from CDN so you don't have to install it via NPM. Maybe use this technique to get started first?

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

Since the `office.js` file injects directly into the global scopes, you can access the APIs from the `window` object. You can find details in that guide.

```
window.Office.doSomething()
window.Excel.doSomething()
window.Word.doSomething()
```